# high volume data storage and processing

Tags: oracle, hadoop, oracle12c, bigdata, nosql

I am building a new application where I am expecting a high volume of geo location data something like a moving object sending geo coordinates every 5 seconds. This data needs to be stored in some database so that it can be used for tracking the moving object on a map anytime. So, I am expecting about 250 coordinates per moving object per route. And each object can run about 50 routes a day. and I have 900 such objects to track. SO, that brings to about 11.5 million geo coordinates to store per day. I have to store about one week of data at least in my database.

This data will be basically used for simple queries like find all the geocoordates for a particular object and a particular route. so, the query is not very complicated and this data will not be used for any analysis purpose.

SO, my question is should I just go with normal Oracle database like 12C distributed over two VMs or should I think about some big data technologies like NO SQL or hadoop?

One of the key requirement is to have high performance. Each query has to respond withing 1 second.

Comment: So you will be making table insert/updates every 5 seconds for 900 objects and when these tables are queried then need to return results in 1 second?

Comment: No, the data will be collected every 5 seconds but inserted into DB every 3 minutes. The data will be queried by an object id which is running the route.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the volume of data (11.5 million)  you can easily simulate the all your scenario in Oracle DB and test it well before.

My suggestions are you need to go for day level partitions & 2 sub partitions like objects & routs.  All your business SQL has to hit right partitions always.

and also you might required to clear older days data. or Some sort of aggregation you can created with past days and delete your raw data would help. 
its well doable 12C.